# How to retrieve data from manytomany table in python django based on its ID

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7, django-models

Suppose there are two tables

> 1. mysql table name : user, Django model name: User
> 2. mysql table video : user, Django model name: Video

User model contain one field as

```
videos = models.ManyToManyField(Video, blank=True, null=True, related_name='video')
```

Now i have a new mysql table name: user_videos

```
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id           | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| video_id          | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

now i need to retrieve data my django like this mysql query: `select * from user_videos order by id desc;`

`user.videos.all()` is giving me order by video.id  not user_videos.id

Any good approach to do this by using models in python django without using a raw query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the join table that Django automatically creates for you by doing:

```
User.videos.through.objects.all()
```

If you need to add more data to your join table, you can set up a many-to-many relationship with the `through` option and specify a custom model:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Thanks. This really helped me.